# Is it possible to exclude certain documents or libraries from a content deployment job?

Tags: content-deployment

I have authoring environment and production environment for my public facing site. Now the requirement that I have is there is one Private document library which should only be available in authoring environment and should never export to production.

Is it possible to exclude certain documents or library from a content deployment job?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please **tag by feature** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

With the way content deployment works (i.e. it replicates the whole content database) this wouldn't be possible.  However, with the correct permissioning on the library, you should be able to make it not visible to users who shouldn't see it.

In addition, I would recommend moving that content somewhere else (i.e. add a content database to the web application and add a new site collection in that content database, like /sites/privatecontent).

Answer (score 0):

This tool may help you : http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/